# How to Add/fetch calendar event without using external package in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

How to Add/fetch calendar event without using external package  in react native.

Answer (score 0):

React native itself suggests using [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker#react-native-datetimepicker) library for date picker as they have built it by merging android and ios datepicker. 
`DatePickerAndroid has been merged with DatePickerIOS and TimePickerAndroid into a single component called DateTimePicker and will be removed in a future release.` so it's better you use this library as it's official.

Comment: I need to add/fetch events from primary calendar in the phone (android/ios) without  using external package